# Remainder Estimate for the Integral Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It states that $\int_{n+1}^{\infty}f(x)dx \leq R_n \leq \int_{n}^{\infty}f(x)dx$, but how can we compare integrals to scalars when they have a unit?

Comment: In the context of calculus, everything is a pure number (or a $n$-uple of pure numbers) and there is no notion of "substance of a number" like in physics.

Comment: An integral does not have to be a measure of area, it can be applied to measure the work done for example which is in Joules by integrating force with respect to displacement.

Comment: True, but it is more about it having a unit. Anyways, thanks @SaucyO'Path